# Python wrapper for ElasticSearch on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, elasticsearch

I'm trying to use the ElasticSearch Python wrapper on Heroku. I have used the Bonsai Heroku add-on, and have received a URL that looks like the one given in the documentation, http://ql9lsrn8:img5ndnsbtaahloy@redwood-94865.us-east-1.bonsai.io/. My question is, how do I connect to this instance using the ElasticSearch Python wrapper?

The documentation (elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#elasticsearch) gives the following example:

```
es = Elasticsearch([
{'host': 'localhost'},
{'host': 'othernode', 'port': 443, 'url_prefix': 'es', 'use_ssl': True},
])
```

Can anyone tell me what values I should use for the host, port and url_prefix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the url heroku gives you has the form of

```
http://username:password@host:port/
```

so you can obtain this information:

```
host: redwood-94865.us-east-1.bonsai.io
port: 80 (implicit)
user_ssl: False (because protocol of that url is http, not https)
username: ql9lsrn8
password: img5ndnsbtaahloy
```

You can learn about this notation on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme).